# Two sample test for equality of 2 dimensional distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, bayesian

I have a large sample from a 2 dimensional continuous unknown distribution. From that sample I could compute any data structure I need to hold an approximation of the sample distribution. This will be constructed only once, so it does not matter if it takes a lot of time.

What I want is to compare with other 2dimensional samples and see if I find evidence that does not come from the same distribution. The trouble is that I have a lot such samples to compare with, and those samples are large and I cannot afford to hold them in memory. So I have to compute an online procedure because data from samples comes from a stream. 
One idea I have is to bin the two sample data and perform a chi squared test. But I am afraid that I will have many zeros if the grid is dense or loose too much power if the grid is sparse. This would also involve a lot of testing to fit the proper grid density.

Do you have any ideas. I am considering smart compact kde approximation with some bayesian update, but I cannot figure out.

Comment: I think what you're after is a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test.

Comment: KS is not an option. I am aware of two dimensional adaptations, the issue is that I. can’t afford to keep all those samples in memory to build the experimental distribution

Comment: [Here](https://normaldeviate.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/modern-two-sample-tests/) is a great blog post that surveys multivariate, two-sample tests. In section 6 of [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf) the authors propose a test with low memory usage for streaming data.

Comment: It's an interesting question.  It might be worth knowing that sparseness in a large grid with large amounts of data for the chi-squared test isn't necessarily a problem.  Indeed, the more data you have, the more zeros you can afford.  Moreover, you don't have to use a chi-squared approximation: you could compute, say, a permutation distribution of the test statistic.  Finally, if you adapt a variable grid to your reference distribution so that each rectangle has substantial probability, then the mere presence of a zero count in *any* of them will be *prima facie* evidence to reject the null.